# Is it appropriate to use the paired-sample t test for this example?

Tags: t-test

If I have 50 people and I ask each one of them to rate Item A (from 1 to 5), Item B (from 1 to 5), Item C (from 1 to 5) and Item D (from 1 to 5) and I want to compare the means of each of the Items to determine whether there is a significant difference - would the paired-samples t test be appropriate?

What is the most straight-forward way to compare the means of Items A, B, C and D?

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do 6 paired t-tests: Item A vs. B, A vs. C, A vs. D, B vs. C, B vs. D and C vs. D.  But that's not what I would recommend. First, it treats the ranks as if they were continuous.  Second, it's messy.

Instead, you should do a nonlinear multilevel model. The independent variable is "item", the random effect is "person", the link is "cumulative logit".  You could then look at the differences among the pairs of items using post hoc tests.

Comment: It wouldn't be valid to do 6 paired t-tests without somehow adjusting the p-values, due to their statistical dependencies.  It's unclear what you mean by "treat the ranks as continuous": a t-test merely treats them as *numbers*; it makes no assumptions, implicit or explicit, about the measurement level.

Comment: Agree that a multilevel model is appropriate. Just making explicit here that the cumulative logit link function means that this is no longer comparing means (which is what a t-test does) but is a multilevel ordinal regression model.

Comment: @whuber Since a t-test adds numbers up and divides them, how does it not make assumptions? They certainly have to be continuous (see http://www.csic.cornell.edu/Elrod/t-test/t-test-assumptions.html or http://www.csic.cornell.edu/Elrod/t-test/t-test-assumptions.html)

Comment: That assertion about "continuous" is simply not correct. (If it were, it would preclude some of the commonest applications of t-tests and ANOVA.)  You appear to confuse measurement type theory with arithmetic.